# Running models on multiple cores with different data sets in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I have a folder containing multiple datasets and I want to run a model over these datasets and distribute the load across multiple cores, hopefully, to increase the overall run time of the data processing.

My computer has 8 cores. This was my first attempt below, it's only really a sketch but using `htop`, I can see that only 1 core is being employed for this job. Multi-core newbie here.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import os
from library_example import model_example

def worker(file_):
    to_save = pd.Series()
    with open(file_,'r') as f_open:
        data = f_open.read()

    # Run model 
    model_results = model_example(file_)

    # Save results in DataFrame
    to_save.to_csv(file_[:-4]+ "_results.csv", model_results )

file_location_ = "/home/datafiles/"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in os.listdir(file_location_):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(file_location_ + filename,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving out the `p.join()`. That will *wait* for the process to complete which effectively makes this a serial process as you kick off the process (i.e. `start`) and then wait for each one (i.e. `join`).  Instead you can try something like this:

```
# construct the workers
workers = [multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(file_location_ + filename,)) for filename in os.listdir(file_location_)]

# start them
for proc in workers:
    proc.start()

# now we wait for them
for proc in workers:
    proc.join()
```

(I didn't try running this in your code but something like that should work.)

**EDIT** If you want to limit the number of workers/processes then I'd recommend just using a `Pool`. You can specify how many processes to use and then `map(..)` the arguments to those processes. Example:

```
# construct a pool of workers
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
pool.map(worker, [file_location_ + filename for filename in os.listdir(file_location_)])
pool.close()
```

Comment: Can I limit the cores used? e.g. 6 out of 8